# Почему Visual Code в автозаполнении не показывает все шрифты?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, шрифты

У меня на ПК установлено множество шрифтов, но когда я пишу `font-family:` в подсказке у меня выводится только определённый набор. Почему он не дополняется теми, что я установил?

Comment: А вы используете какое-нибудь расширение для css или используете стандартный функционал?

Comment: Нет, никаких расширений не использую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, почитав немного документации и прочего, я пришёл к выводу, что Visual Code в подсказках отображает только "безопасные" шрифты.

> Безопасные шрифты - это шрифты, которые установлены на большинство
> устройств, а значит достаточно прописать название шрифта чтоб браузер
> пользователя корректно его отобразил.